# How to ignore tokens in facettes from solr

Tags: solr

I am using within Solr 6.41:

> WordDelimiterFilterFactory

in order to search for strings containing dots without them beeing in the query.

> "00120123" (returning result also 001.20.123)

The problem is, that the field also supplies a facette, which now shows the tokens instead of the entire field.

Tokens are generated within the field type text_wd:

```
<fieldType name="text_wd" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="refnumber" type="text_wd" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

Facettes containing tokens:

```
001 (1324)
20 (909)
123 (480)
```

Desired facette:

```
001.20.123
```

How can I keep the desired functionality and in the same time not have the tokens within the facette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate field for your facets. Facets uses the underlying token structure to generate values, and you'll have to keep the field as a single value to be able to get the kind of facets you want.

Use a separate field with a type that uses the StrField type, and then use a copyField instruction to move the content from `refnumber` into that field as well.

```
<field name="refnumber" type="text_wd" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
<field name="refnumber_facet" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" />
<copyField source="refnumber" dest="refnumber_facet"  />
```

Comment: This looks like I need to change  my application in order to retrieve facettes from another field but search another. What does the copyField do, will a reindex not simply get the field anyway withh the copy?

Comment: The copyField copies the submitted content for `source` into the field given in `dest` as well, so you don't have to modify your application to submit content into both fields (just to facet on the second field). This is useful when you have the same content that you want to process in many different ways.